# Bokeh dropdown menu options from a column unique values

Tags: python, menu, bokeh

I'm trying to create a dropdown menu with Bokeh. The menu options should be added from a list. I have created the list and the menu with Bokeh, but no options are displayed in the menu. Please give me some advice how to solve this. Thank you!

The dataframe:
[image]

First, I created the list of options from dataframe column "Continent".

```
options = data['Continent']

def unique(list): 

    # intilize a null list 
    unique_list = [] 

    # traverse for all elements 
    for x in list: 
        # check if exists in unique_list or not 
        if x not in unique_list: 
            unique_list.append(x) 
    # print list 
    for x in unique_list: 
        print(x)

options = unique(data['Continent'])
```

Then I created the menu with bokeh:

```
from bokeh.models.widgets import Dropdown
# Import output_file and show from bokeh.io
from bokeh.io import output_file, show
from bokeh.layouts import widgetbox

menu_widget = [options]
menu_dropdown = Dropdown(label = "Menu", menu=menu_widget)
output_file("dropdown.html")
show(widgetbox(menu_dropdown))
```

The problem is that no option is displayed in the menu (see the pic bellow).
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> First, I created the list of options from dataframe column "Continent".

If you're using Pandas, then that whole code can be replaced with just `data['Continent'].unique()`. If you're not using Pandas, then you can use `list(set(data['Continent']))` or `sorted(set(data['Continent']))`.

As of know your `unique` function returns `None` instead of the list of unique items.

> The problem is that no option is displayed in the menu

Apart from the issue with returning `None` above, the `menu` argument must be either a list of strings of a list of tuples of strings. But you pass a list wrapped in a list. Instead, try using just `menu=options`.

Comment: I have created the options using data['Continent'].unique(), then I passed the options to the menu, menu=options. Got this error: ValueError: expected an element of List(Either(String, Tuple(String, Either(String, Instance(Callback))))), got array(['ASI', 'NAM', 'LAT', 'AF', 'EUR', 'OCE'], dtype=object)

Comment: Worked with options = list(set(data['Continent'])), and then menu=options. Thank you!